# Access request variable in Django CreateView form_valid method

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

How do I access request in form_valid ?

```
def redirect_logic_func(request):
   #redirect logic

class CView(CreateView):
    form_class = CForm
    template_name = "c_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        super(CView, self).form_valid(form)
        return redirect_logic_func(self.request)
```

Is self.request.POST the same as request.POST ?

Comment: What is the 'trouble' you are having? `self.request.POST` in `form_valid` should work.

Comment: Is request.POST same as self.request.POST?

Comment: I am guessing here because your question is very vague - You are passing `self.request.POST` to your `redirect_logic_func` method, which is expecting a `request`; if in this method you have a line such as `request.POST` then this  will fail; you probably want to pass in the complete request, like this `return redirect_logic_func(self.request)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. To access the `request` variable in `form_valid()`, you just need to use `self.request`. This will provide you with the `request` variable.
2. No, there is no need to override the `.post()` to access the `request` variable in `form_valid()`.
3. Yes, `self.request.POST` is the same as `request.POST` as they are the same `request` object.

So, your final code should look like:

```
def redirect_logic_func(request):
   #redirect logic

class CView(CreateView):
    form_class = CForm
    template_name = "c_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        super(CView, self).form_valid(form)
        return redirect_logic_func(self.request) # use self.request
```

Comment: Great, I even did some customization before saving the model (I used modelForm) by overriding the form_valid method